# Пишу бота для группы вконтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу пота вконтакте. При отправки сообщения Начать два раза подряд появляется ошибка.`
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\bot_zadach\main.py", line 68, in <module>
users_id = user.prov(users_id)
File "F:\bot_zadach\main.py", line 19, in prov
if id in users_id:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Не могу понять почему она возникает это ведь просто проверка условия

```
import vk_api
from vk_api import VkUpload
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from kluch import token
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
longpull = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)

class Bot():

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def prov(self, users_id):
        if id in users_id:
            flag = 0
        else:
            flag = 1
        if flag == 1:
            users_id.append(id)
        with open ('id.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(id))
            f.write('\n')
        return users_id

    def sozd_spis(self, fullname):
        with open (id + '.txt', 'a', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            f.write(fullname)






def kb(self):
    keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=False)
    keyboard.add_button(label="Ссылка", color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
    keyboard.add_button(label="Фото1", color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpull = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
upload = VkUpload(vk_session)

with open ('id.txt', 'r') as f:
users_id = f.read()
users_id = users_id.split(' ')
print(users_id)


def send_msg(id, msg):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': msg, 'random_id': get_random_id()})

for event in longpull.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:

        msg = event.text
        id = str(event.user_id)
        user = Bot(id)
        spis = ''

        if msg == 'Начать':
            users_id = user.prov(users_id)
            user_name = vk.method("users.get", {"user_ids": id})  
            fullname = user_name[0]['first_name'] #+ ' ' + user_name[0]['last_name']
            send_msg(id, 'Привет {} \n Но я буду звать тебя уебище'.format(fullname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря все просто, у вас `users_id` равен `None` поэтому и появляется такая ошибка.

Например:

```
>>> a = None
>>> if 'a' in a:
...     print(a)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Сам код считывания из файла написан верно (не считая отступов, конечно =))

Но я подозреваю, что сам файл `id.txt` пуст.

Comment: в том то и дело, что это файл не пустой

Comment: Вырежьте кусок кода считывающий файл и запустите его отдельно от скрипта. `users_id` видны?

Comment: Дойдите дебаггером до строки `users_id = user.prov(users_id)` и проверьте чему равен users.id, до передачи его в `user.prov`. Либо до этой строки, вставьте print(users_id). И проверьте  вывод.